# Simulating onClick calls with child components in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm building a tic-tac-toe game and able to have two players play against each other. Now I want to simulate randomness on Play O. Part of the randomness, is getting one of the 9 children components, "PositionedComponent", to simulate the computer doing the click and have it change the display.

I thought using useRef() and .click() would allow for this simulation. I created an array of useRef() and in each PositionedComponent, I give them each a useRef(). Then inside of useEffect() I thought of creating a random number and then call the click function in autoClick[randomValue].current.click()

I always get an undefined value for autoClick but I'm not sure why when I initialized it at the top.

I've also tried declaring the array as autoClick = useState(Array(9).fill(useRef())) as well as doing autoClick = [useRef()...,useRef()] and still the same undefined value issue.

Another method I tried using was document.getElementById("") but still the same undefined value issue. I'm not sure what is the issue since I'm declaring the autoClick at the top but still gettin undefined value. Thank you for any advice.

```
function TicTacToeGrid()
{
  // Your tic-tac-toe logic goes here
  const [playersMove, setPlayersMove] = useState(true);
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState('');
  const [currPosition, setCurrPosition] = useState(23)
  const [board, setBoard] = useState(Array(9).fill('-'));
  const [game, setGame] = useState(false)
  const  [tie, setTie] = useState(false)
  const autoClick = []

  for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  {
    autoClick[i] = useRef();
  }
 

  
  const handlePlayersTurn = async (position) =>
  {
    console.log("auto click is", autoClick)
    if(playersMove)
    {
      setSymbol('X')
    }
    else
    {
      setSymbol('O')
    }
    setPlayersMove(!playersMove)    
    setCurrPosition(position)
  };
  
  const positon1 =  <PositionedComponent x="0px" y = "0px" ref={autoClick[0]} playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() => handlePlayersTurn(1)}/>
  const positon2 =  <PositionedComponent x="210px" y = "0px" ref={autoClick[1]} playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(2)}/>
  const positon6 =  <PositionedComponent x="420px" y = "0px"  ref={autoClick[2]}  playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(3)}/>
  const positon3 =  <PositionedComponent x="0px" y = "210px"  ref={autoClick[3]} playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(4)}/>
  const positon4 =  <PositionedComponent x="210px" y = "210px" ref={autoClick[4]}  playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(5)}/>
  const positon7 =  <PositionedComponent x="420px" y = "210px" ref={autoClick[5]} playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(6)}/>
  const positon5 =  <PositionedComponent x="0px" y = "420px"  ref={autoClick[6]}  playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(7)}/>
  const positon9 =  <PositionedComponent x="210px" y = "420px" ref={autoClick[7] playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(8)}/>
  const positon8 =  <PositionedComponent x="420px" y = "420px" ref={autoClick[8]} playersMove={playersMove} handlePlayersTurn={() =>handlePlayersTurn(9)}/>
  
  useEffect(()=>
  {
    if(playersMove)
    {
      console.log("X turn")
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("O turn")
      const randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      autoClick[randomValue].current.click()
    }
    const newBoard = board
    newBoard[currPosition-1] = symbol
    const finalBoard = newBoard
    setBoard(finalBoard);
    setGame(isWinner(finalBoard, symbol));
    setTie(catScratch(board))
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The `autoClick` was an initialised empty array in the component body, not triggering re-renders. This leads to undefined refs in the `useEffect`.

try:

```js
const autoClick = Array(9).fill(null).map(() => useRef());
```

Answer (score 0):

In React everything is controlled by state / props. Instead of simulating a click, just change the state directly by calling `handlePlayersTurn(position)`.

In addition, you have too much states. If you need to derive a value (`symbol` from `playerMove` for example), you don't need a different state, just compute it on the fly.

**Note**: this example doesn't include winning / tie conditions. When there are no more cells, the `useEffect` would be skipped. In addition, only open cells would have a click handler.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

const initGame = () => Array.from({ length: 9 }, (_, i) => ({
  position: i,
}))

function TicTacToeGrid() {
  const [playersMove, setPlayersMove] = useState(true)
  const [board, setBoard] = useState(initGame)
  
  const handlePlayersTurn = position => {
    // compute the symbol when you need it
    const value = playersMove ? 'X' : 'O'
    
    // update the board using the previous board state
    setBoard(b => b.toSpliced(position, 1, {
      position,
      value
    }))
    
    // update the current player
    setPlayersMove(p => !p)
  }
  
  // compute available positions
  const availablePositions = board.filter(c => !c.value)
    
  useEffect(() => {
    // if it's the player's turn or no more positions, skip
    if(playersMove || availablePositions.length === 0) return
    
    // find an open position
    const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * availablePositions.length)
    
    // call handlePlayersTurn with open position found
    handlePlayersTurn(availablePositions[idx].position)
  }, [playersMove, availablePositions])
  
  return (
    <div className="board">
      {board.map(({ position, value }) => (
        <div
          {...!value && { onClick: () => handlePlayersTurn(position) }}
          className="cell" 
          key={position}>
          {value || '-'}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<TicTacToeGrid />)
```

```css
.board {
  display: grid;
  height: 50vmin;
  width: 50vmin;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```